# Get the file path based on the current working directory?

Tags: ruby, compass-sass

How do I turn the following absolute path:

```
/path/to/some/file/that/i/need.file
```

into the relative path:

```
file/that/i/need.file
```

when I am in the `/path/to/some` directory?

I want to take an absolute file path and split it at the current working directory so that I have the path of the filename that starts at the current working directory.

I'm running this from within the `on_stylesheet_saved` callback in a Compass config.rb.

Comment: `/file/that/i/need` is not an relative path, because it starts with `/`, which bases it at the root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just do something like follows.

```
absolute_path.split(Dir.pwd.to_s)[1].sub('/','')
```

This gets a 2 element array where the second element is the remaining portion of the path you want.  The sub then strips off the prefixing forward slash.

Comment: This is half way there to being correct for me but only because I was incorrect in stating that I wanted ```\file/that/i/need``` (which your solution is giving me) when I really need ```file/that/i/need```, minus the beginning slash. Can you update your answer to reflect the change to my original question?

Comment: I've updated the answer above; it just strips the starting forward slash off.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use the [Pathname](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-relative_path_from) class:

```
full_dir = Pathname.new('/path/to/some/file/that/i/need')
base_dir = Pathname.new('/path/to/some')
full_dir.relative_path_from(base_dir).to_s # => "file/that/i/need"
```

Here's what [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-relative_path_from) says about Pathname:

> Pathname represents the name of a file or directory on the filesystem, but not the file itself.
>
> The pathname depends on the Operating System: Unix, Windows, etc. This library works with pathnames of local OS, however non-Unix pathnames are supported experimentally.
>
> A Pathname can be relative or absolute. It’s not until you try to reference the file that it even matters whether the file exists or not.
>
> Pathname is immutable. It has no method for destructive update.
>
> The goal of this class is to manipulate file path information in a neater way than standard Ruby provides....

Comment: I clarified my question a little bit which would change your answer seeing as full_dir is actually a specific file and not a directory.

Comment: I don't see why you would include the Pathname class for something this simple.  It is 4 lines of code (including the require not listed in your example) to do something that can be done in 1 line of code.  It's not that the Pathname lib doesn't have a place, but it isn't necessary for every case.  I prescribe to the philosophy of "Every line of code is a liability."

Comment: @spencercarnage, Pathname doesn't care whether the last element is a file or directory. The result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following expressions

```
absolute_path.gsub(Dir.pwd, '')
```

In this case it will return the relative path if the current directory is part of the absolute path, otherwise it will return the full path

Comment: You don't need `gsub` for this.

Comment: This doesn't return a relative path, it's absolute.

Comment: It takes the absolute_path and remove current path from it, which turns it into a relative path